# The count number of pressed button

Tags: java, button, count, javafx, mouse

I need that when I press the button to show me how many times was the button pressed. I use this method, but on console still show me the number 1.

Here is code:

```
 button_help.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

    int count = 0;
    count ++;

        System.out.println(count);
    }


 });
```

Comment: You re-define your count variable everytime. So it will go back to 0 everytime you click it. It will be best to define it outside the handle scope.

Comment: But I do not mean to get count when the mouse is double or triple clicked. I want to get count when the button is just once pressed.

Comment: declare count globally instead of locally

Comment: For checking if it is a double click, refer to the [link][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051659/identifying-double-click-in-java

Comment: In your code int count = 0;declare in inside of event handler.so every   time create new count count will print 1.declare count out side

Answer (score 3):

Your solution doesn´t work as you are reseting the value of variable every time you click button. You have to define it once and than just increase the valu of it.

Solution:

```
int count = 0;

button_help.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        count++;
        System.out.println(count);
    }

});
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained what you're doing here and why the solution in the question doesn't work.

Comment: Edited as requested :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the int outside of the event handler or you just reset it each time the button is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

Like I said before: You re-define your count variable every time. So it will go back to 0 every time you click it. It will be best to define it outside the handle scope.

This should work (just define the count variable globally):

```
int count = 0;
button_help.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        count ++;

        System.out.println(count);
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks much, I did not realize it. Now it works. Thanks