# How to setText on TextField from Run() method, using JavaFX Scene Builder?

Tags: java, multithreading, textfield

I have a controller Class extends Thread,

and my Run() method, just do this.

```
private int con = 1;

public void Run(){
   while(true){
      try{
          con++;
          print();
      catch(exception e){
          system.out.prinln(e);
      }
   }
}
```

and here's the problem,i need a print() method, to show "con" on a TextField.

I have a frmMain.fxml and the frmMainController.java class.

How i can show my "con", when clicked a button from my interface. (evt onClickedMouse).

i have this:

```
  private TextField tf;
    private FrmMainController fr;

    public void show(){
       tf.setText(String.valueOf(con));
       fr.setTxtThread1(tf); 
    }
```

I would appreciate someone help me to get over this.

Comment: So you have to create `button` component first. same issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524583/the-count-number-of-pressed-button

Comment: Show .fxml file too..TextField object has to be initialized before used or else is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying JavaFX Components in other Thread can cause problems.

Although in your run method you can do it using `Platform.runLater(...);`

In your fxml file add an identifier(fx:id) for your  `TextField`
then your Controlled class has to implement `Initializable` interface which has a method that will be called when all your fxml elements have been initialized.

As soon as this happen you can call your `Run` method and update the `TextField` as described above.

Basically in the SceneBuilder create a basic layout with a TextField and a Button which have fixed id.Then add an `actionListener` to the button inside the method of `Initializable` interface:

```
button.setOnAction(a->{···});
```

Comment: Thank you my friend. I have a lot to learn.

I will try to do all what u say to me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: @Chopi I will add the code as soon as i get to computer,cause i am most answering from phone.

Comment: thanks man, sorry i answer now.

Im learnign Web Developers and i have no time x.x

Comment: @Chopi  HTML,CSS3,Javascipt,Node.js,W3.css ... ;)