# Mouse event goes through the component

Tags: java, swing

I have added a simple program to illustrate.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleInternalFrame extends Frame
{

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  static JLayeredPane desktop;

  JInternalFrame internalFrame;

  public SimpleInternalFrame()
  {
    super("Internal Frame Demo");
    setSize(500, 400);


    Panel p = new Panel();


    add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
    {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
      {
        System.exit(0);
      }
    });


    desktop = new JDesktopPane();
    desktop.setOpaque(true);
    add(desktop, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }


  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    SimpleInternalFrame sif = new SimpleInternalFrame();
    sif.setVisible(true);

    final JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("Internal Frame 1", true, true, true, true);
    internalFrame.setBounds(50, 50, 300, 200);
    desktop.add(internalFrame, new Integer(1));
    JTextField tf = new JTextField();
    tf.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt)
      {

        System.out.println("Text Field " + evt.getClickCount());
      }
    });
    internalFrame.add(tf);
    internalFrame.setVisible(true);

    final JInternalFrame internalFrame2 = new JInternalFrame("Internal Frame 1", true, true, true, true);
    internalFrame2.setBounds(50, 50, 200, 100);
    desktop.add(internalFrame2, new Integer(1));
    JButton jb = new JButton("click me");
    jb.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt)
      {

        if (evt.getClickCount() == 1)
        {
          System.out.println("Button " + evt.getClickCount());
          internalFrame2.setVisible(false);
        }
      }
    });
    internalFrame2.add(jb);
    internalFrame2.setVisible(true);

  }
}
```

When running the code it will open a two internal frames.One has button.One has text field.Button will close the first Internal frame for single click.

Double click the button.It will show click count 2 as in text field.
This is the problem we have currently in the project.Thing is second frame dose not has text field in actual project.It has click-able item that work in double click event.
This is the problem we have currently.Please help.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: question is if we double click the calender button it will fire double click event to under component.In there text box.Thin if we had another button their it action also fired.

Comment: I don't think so, but you can pretty easily try with some actionlisteners

Comment: I have added a simple code to illustrate.

Comment: You could implement your own double click checking on your `JTextField` with a `Timer` and not the provided `getClickCount()` method. There is an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18990721/21926

Comment: The thing is we can not change text field code.Then we need to correct so many  such places.Only need to implement a logic that button does not pass the double click to the text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While searching on internet and reading some documents i was able get a solution.

```
        int timerinterval = (int) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().
                              getDesktopProperty("awt.multiClickInterval");

        final Timer timer = new Timer(timerinterval, new ActionListener()
        {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent acEvt)
          {
            internalFrame2.setVisible(false);
          }
        });

        jb.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
          public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent evt)
          {
            System.out.println("Button " + evt.getClickCount());
            timer.setRepeats(false);
            timer.start();
            if (evt.getClickCount() > 1)
            {
              timer.restart();
            }
          }
        });
```

One draw back of this solution is if user do a single click he need to wait 
**timerinterval** unnecessarily.Any one has better solution please post.

Answer (score 1):

```
tf.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    int cc;

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
        int ccount = evt.getClickCount();
        if(ccount == 1 || ccount == cc+1) {
            cc = ccount;
            System.out.println("Text Field " + evt.getClickCount());
        }
    }
});
```

This will work more than once.

Another possibility is to use components with overriden processMouseEvent():

```
public class SimpleInternalFrame extends Frame {
...
    private MouseEvent lastMouseEvent;

    public boolean checkEvent(MouseEvent e) {
        if(lastMouseEvent != null) {
            if(lastMouseEvent.getSource() != e.getSource()) {
                if(e.getClickCount() != 1) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        lastMouseEvent = e;
        return true;
    }

    class MTextField extends JTextField {
        protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e) {
            if (checkEvent(e)) {
                super.processMouseEvent(e);
            }
        }
    }

    class MButton extends JButton {
        protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e) {
            if (checkEvent(e)) {
                super.processMouseEvent(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public JTextField createText() {
        return new MTextField();
    }

    public MButton createButton() {
        return new MButton();
    }
} //end of SimpleInternalFrame
```

create components:

```
final JTextField tf = sif.createText();
tf.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
        System.out.println("Text Field " + evt.getClickCount());
    }
});

JButton jb = sif.createButton();
jb.setText("click me");
jb.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getClickCount() == 1) {
            internalFrame2.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Cannot add logic to text field.Then need to correct so many places.Need to some how stop passing double click to text field.Thanks any way.

Comment: Second option is much better.But think we do not have access the code of JTextField.Because it is a another module developed by another team.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static boolean called myTurn initialized to false and then in the textfield mouseClicked:

```
tf.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt)
            {
                if (evt.getClickCount() >= 2 && !myTurn) {
                    myTurn = true;
                    evt.consume();
                } else {
                    myTurn = true; //Initial one click on me
                    System.out.println("Text Field " + evt.getClickCount());
                    evt.consume();
                }
            }
        });
```

This solves your problem in this basic case, but I don't know if it will in your application. The problem is that if you click the TextField before the Button, you can experience the same problem. However, if that isn't possible, this will solve it.

Comment: Some how need to stop passing double click from the button.Can not add extra logic to text field.